# Send captured characters back to the process

Tags: ruby, terminal

Right now, I have the following code to capture a character in ruby using the IO.read,

```
tty_param = `stty -g`
system 'stty raw -echo'

capt = IO.read '/dev/stdin', 1

system "stty #{tty_param}"
```

The code is called through a key-binding, so I'll be in the middle of an application like vim or just the bash prompt, when this is called.

What I'm wondering is, how do I send the characters back to my process once I've finished running my program?

Answer (score 2):

[Open3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) can be what you are looking for.

> Open3 grants you access to stdin, stdout, stderr and a thread to wait
>   for the child process when running another program. You can specify
>   various attributes, redirections, current directory, etc., of the
>   program in the same way as for Process.spawn.